# Isolated extensions

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-extensions

Since 1.8 it is possible to make web parts isolated, https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/isolated-web-parts. I wonder if there is any way to make an extension isolated aswell? I'm developing a list extension that will need permissions to the users mailbox. I would not like all extensions/web parts to have these permissions and therefore I look at how to isolate the permissions to the extension.

At the moment I'm leaning towards creating a web api and register that as an application and let the extension communicate with that. It will not be a prefect solution since it will open up for some possibilities but the attack surface is more controlled and the attacker must be aware of how my api works. Of course the customer needs to be made aware of the security concerns and accept the risk.